# Does "A or B with C" mean "A with C or B with C" or "B with C or A"?

Tags: prepositions

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge truck or a Toyota truck with a crew cab.

Does "with a crew cab" apply to both trucks or just the Toyota?

Comment: It's ambiguous.  It can be interpreted either way.

Answer (score 2):

It is inconclusive.

If you want it to be a crew cab for both:

> Qualified vehicles must have a crew cab and be either a Dodge or Toyota truck.

If you want the crew cab to be one or the other:

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Toyota truck with a crew cab, or a Dodge truck.

Answer (score -1):

A person speaking might intend it to include both, but "crew cab" is grammatically only tied to the Toyota. There is nothing that links it to the Dodge.  Consider an alternative:

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge truck or a Toyota truck with a red trim.

Would you still wonder if the Dodge needed a red trim? Again, the speaker might intend it that way, but that is not what it says. It doesn't say that a Dodge with a red trim is favorable or unfavorable. A factor that reduces the linkage even further is the word **truck** is repeated. Consider:

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge or Toyota truck with a red trim.

Now "red trim" is linked with "truck", which is linked to both brands.

So, back to the original example, I would reword it for clarity:

> Qualified trucks must have crew cabs and be of either Dodge or Toyota brands.

Answer (score -1):

Most people will understand your sentence

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge truck or a Toyota truck with a crew cab.

as

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge truck *with a crew cab* or a Toyota truck *with a crew cab*.
>   because they will know that trucks may have crew cabs, so it is possible for both Dodge and Toyota trucks to have crew cabs, so they will interrupt it this way.

Others less knowledgable might understand it to mean

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge truck, or a Toyota truck with a crew cab.

where *with a crew cab* only applies to Toyota trucks and Dodge trucks being a separate category.

To be less ambiguous

> Qualified vehicles must either be a Dodge truck or a Toyota truck and *be equipped* with a crew cab.

the additional "be equipped" puts *with a crew cab* on the same level requirement as the make of the truck.